# Does this use of std::make_unique lead to non-unique pointers?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Suppose I have the following code in C++:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Some {
        Some(int _a) : a(_a) {}
        int a;
};

int main() {
        Some some(5);

        std::unique_ptr<Some> p1 = std::make_unique<Some>(some);
        std::unique_ptr<Some> p2 = std::make_unique<Some>(some);

        std::cout << p1->a << " " << p2->a << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

As I understand, unique pointers are used to guarantee that resources are not shared. But in this case both `p1` and `p2` point to the same instance `some`.

Please unveil the situation.

Comment: Your situation would have been easy to diagnose if you had printed the pointer values themselves rather than the `a` field of the pointees. Or it you had made a "loud" copy constructor. Also, your most basic error was probably to think `make_unique` erects a pointer to a given object (here the local variable `some`); this is not what it does, or is for.

Comment: I'm utterly astonished that this poor post got so many upvotes. What's wrong with SO?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They don't point to the *same* resource, they each point to a different *copy* of it. You can illustrate it  by deleting the copy constructor to see the error:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Some {
        Some(int _a) : a(_a) {}
        Some(Some const&) = delete;
        int a;
};

int main() {
        Some some(5);

        std::unique_ptr<Some> p1 = std::make_unique<Some>(some); //error here
        std::unique_ptr<Some> p2 = std::make_unique<Some>(some);

        std::cout << p1->a << " " << p2->a << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out though that `unique_ptr` has no means of enforcing unique ownership. A careless programmer may easily share ownership of the same object between two distinct `unique_ptr`s, which will most likely result in undefined behavior at runtime.

Comment: @ComicSansMS, you are 100% correct. But I'm ambivalent about adding an example the shows how it can be done...

Comment: I tend to agree. No need to show people how to blow their own legs off.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: That's a good reason to enforce the practice of only creating `unique_ptr`s with `std::make_unique`.

Answer (score 16):

`std::make_unique` creates objects, calling constructor with specified arguments.

You passed `Some&` as parameter, and here copy constructor was invoked, and new object constructed.

So, p1 and p2 are 2 absolutely different pointers, but constructed from same object, using copy constructor

Answer (score 9):

> both `p1` and `p2` point to the same instance `some`

[No, they don't.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3bc457a1634dcbf)

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Some {
        Some(int _a) : a(_a) {}
        int a;
};

int main() {
        Some some(5);

        std::unique_ptr<Some> p1 = std::make_unique<Some>(some);
        std::unique_ptr<Some> p2 = std::make_unique<Some>(some);

        std::cout << p1->a << " " << p2->a << std::endl;
        p1->a = 42;
        std::cout << p1->a << " " << p2->a << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

output:

```
5 5
42 5
```

Answer (score 1):

To test whether two pointers point to the same object instance, you should compare the locations they point to, instead of the object member variables:

```
std::cout << &(*p1) << " " << &(*p2) << std::endl;
```

Which will show that they indeed do *not* point to the same instance.

ADDENDUM: As pointed out by Remy Lebeau, since C++11 it is advisable to use the
[`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) function for this purpose, which obtains the actual address of an object even if the `&` operator is overloaded:

```
std::cout << std::addressof(*p1) << " " << std::addressof(*p2) << std::endl;
```

Comment: This code would fail if the class implements a custom `operator&`. That is what `std::addressof()` was introduced to solve: `std::cout << std::addressof(*p1) << " " << std::addressof(*p2) << std::endl;`

Comment: You are right, thank you. For the given example, it isn't necessary, but it certainly makes sense to use it anyway. I added it to the answer.