# Use of smart pointers for copy elision vs. local automatic storage

Tags: c++

Does the use of a `unique_pointer` here extend the life of `local_line` itself (avoiding a copy), or does `make_unique` need to copy it when constructing the new `unique_ptr` ?

```cpp
  typedef vector<string> Line;
  typedef vector< unique_ptr<Line> > Page;
  void addLine(Page& pg) {
    Line local_line;
    // fill local_line with strings
    pg.push_back( make_unique<Line>(local_line) );
  }
  Page p; addLine(p);
```

Comment: No, `local_line` is a local variable it goes out of scope when the function returns. Instead, a copy of it is made when using `make_unique`

Comment: you cannot "extend the lifetime" of `local_line`. When it goes out of scope its lifetime ends, there is no way around that. Did you read documentation of `std::make_unique` ? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique

Comment: See dupe: [Why std::make_unique calls copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019871/why-stdmake-unique-calls-copy-constructor) and also the answer in [Does this use of std::make_unique lead to non-unique pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911466/does-this-use-of-stdmake-unique-lead-to-non-unique-pointers)

Comment: its unclear why you think you need `local_line`. What you can do with `local_line` you can do as well with `*(pg.back())` after you pushed the line to the vector

Comment: std::vector has a move constructor, so there is no need to do anything fance. Just use pg.emplace_back(Line {}); to add a line.

Comment: The referred questions are very helpful but are not duplicates. They are not set in the context of local storage/return/lifespan context (which is why I didn't find them). Also, my question concerns a std. container with a move constructor which makes for Pepijn's very helpful comment that does not apply to referred questions.

Comment: The "make" in `make_unique` and `make_shared` means "create"; they always create a new object. You can't change the ownership of automatic objects - they are "owned" by the variable scope. I sometimes put it as the "make" being creational as in "make me a pizza", not transformational as in "make me a millionaire".

Comment: @molbdnilo : yep. Me too, I don't consider I really understood something until I can boil it down to a "pizza-level sentence" :) Thank you for the mozzarella. Bottom line, I'll be "making" `new Objects`s to go when move ctor not available.. and `unique_ptr` will ferry that around and clean up the bread crumbs.